# .csv tax file only uses the *last* line of the file for tax rates

Tags: magento-1.9, import, tax, csv

Can someone look at a .csv tax file and tell me what I'm doing wrong with it? It is totally ignoring all the lines in the file, and only using the zip code in the last line of the file to produce tax estimates. Don't know how to upload file here...so here is the text..:

```
"Code","Country","State","Zip/Post Code","Rate","Zip/Post is Range","Range From","Range To","default","wonderbrella"
"GA","US","GA","30075","9.0000","","","","",""
"GA","US","GA","30067","7.0000","","","","",""
```

Answer (score 4):

Only the last line of the file is importing because you are using the same 'code' for 2 different tax rates.  In the tax rates table 'code' is a unique field (like 'sky' is to a product) and therefore you cannot have to rates with the same 'code'.

In order to import both of these rates you need to use a different 'code', for example, differentiate the code using the zip/post code (and/or rate):

```
"Code","Country","State","Zip/Post Code","Rate","Zip/Post is Range","Range From","Range To","default","wonderbrella"
"GA-30075","US","GA","30075","9.0000","","","","",""
"GA-30067","US","GA","30067","7.0000","","","","",""
```

### Further explanation

The reason only the last row is importing is because the following is happening:

- The first row is importing a rate with the code 'GA'
- The second row is updating the record created from the first row as the 'code' matches (again like creating and updating a product with the same 'sky')

If you tried to set both these up manually in the admin area, the first rate would be saved fine, but when you got to the point of saving the second rate you would get an error 'Code already exists.' to inform you the 'code' already exists.